# Como guardar una copia de una imagen al utilizar libreria gd php

Tags: php

Necesito guardar 2 imagenes una editada y otra sin editar. 
al editar mi imagen con imagecreatefromjpeg($img); quisiera guardarla en el mismo directorio con otro nombre para tener las 2 imagenes. La editada y la original.

Comment: podrías compartir algo del código que tienes? así podemos ver donde puedes tener el problema

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría que lo hicieses en dos pasos:

1.- Guardar la imagen que te suben en la carpeta que quieras

```
copy($_FILES['txtfile']['tmp_name'], $dirdestino);
```

2.- Luego con la librería GD, guardar la imagen retocada

```
imagecopyresampled($imagen_nueva, $imagen_vieja, 0, 0, 0, 0,$nuevo_ancho, $nuevo_alto, $ancho, $alto);
imagejpeg($imagen_nueva,$destino);
imagedestroy($imagen_nueva);
imagedestroy($imagen_vieja);
```

Si pones el código que tienes, quizá sea también mas fácil ayudarte